# Using an NSMutableArray of weak pointers

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, properties, attributes

This is a purely theoretical question so please feel free to propose additional constraints or suggest alternative questions to discussion.

I know that in Objective-C almost any property that is mutable ought to be defined as `(nonatomic, copy)`, but what if I want that property, say a mutable array, to be only just a list of weak pointers to objects already retained by some other class? For example, say I have a class called `Concept` and let's assume that *all* intended `Concept` instances have already been loaded and retained in memory somewhere by some class other than `Concept`. Say we add a nonatomic `NSMutableArray` property to each `Concept` instance called `relatedConcepts` that points to other `Concept` instances that are retained and already exist in memory.

What I know is that NSArrays are lists of strong referenced objects, but I want a list of weak referenced objects. How might I go about implementing this?

Comment: @CrimsonChris is it reasonable to want a list of weak pointers and if so, how do you go about doing that?

Comment: By the way do you mind posting your comment as an answer so I can mark it correct? Your comment was very helpful

Comment: NSArray keep strong reference to the object. If you want to keep weak reference to an object you can use vector structure from objective-c++

Comment: I have found some scenarios where keeping an array of weak references has come in handy. I've had to roll my own solution for that using weak proxies. Basically, you have an array of objects that then have a weak reference to the objects you actually care about. The weak proxy then needs to redirect all of the calls to it to the object it wraps.

Comment: Ok I think I am better understanding these references now. So which case(s) do you know of specifically that actually need weak references? Multiple delegate objects?

Comment: A "multi-delegate" solution is indeed one such scenario.

Comment: I assume in the "multi-delgate" scenario it would have to be really weird since you ought to be able to define each delegate individually, and otherwise in an array with proxy pointers... Boy that is really messy. I'd be curious to know what project you needed an array of delegates for

Comment: It's an alternative to using notifications. With enough encapsulation, it's cleaner. I like being able to say `[objectThatHasManyDelegates addDelegate:self]` and that's the end of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An NSArray ALWAYS keeps a strong reference to each of its items. This is by design as arrays are nil terminated and would become corrupted if one of the items ever became nil. The weak you are referring to would only apply to the array reference itself. Keeping "weak" items in an array is an advanced problem. My current solution involves using weak proxy objects which sounds kind of like what you were describing in your last paragraph. Whether you use copy or not isn't really relevant.

I have found some scenarios where keeping an array of weak references has come in handy. I've had to roll my own solution for that using weak proxies. Basically, you have an array of objects that then have a weak reference to the objects you actually care about. The weak proxy then needs to redirect all of the calls to it to the object it wraps.

Comment: What of the case in which the array of pointers is infinitely long such that not all objects can possibly really stay in memory but if it encounters a released object that should be memory just reloads it and puts it back?

Comment: That... sounds like a completely different problem.

Comment: Is it a reasonable problem? Or not something worth implementing? Has it been done already using a system structure/function?

Comment: "Infinite" is hard to represent in computer science. I'd advise you to post another question.

Comment: Thanks Crimson. I meant infinite in sense of variable length/magnitude. By the way I edited my question. Do you mind editing your answer to include your comment about multiple delegates?

Answer (score 1):

You would use the `strong` specifier for your `relatedConcepts` property. That's to keep that instance from disappearing out from underneath you, regardless of the number or kind of references it contains.

There's no such thing as a mutable array that's a "list of `weak` pointers." `NSMutableArray` (as well as `NSArray`) maintains `strong` references to its members.

You're worrying far too much about what's retained (has a `strong` reference to it) and what isn't. That isn't your job. It's entirely possible that whatever is holding a `strong` reference to an object may choose to release it. Meanwhile, if nothing else is holding a `strong` reference to it, your `weak` reference falls to nil. Bad idea if you want to keep using it.

Comment: If I make two strong references to the same object in memory does it take up twice the memory?

Comment: No. Just two strong references.

Comment: @Savagewood No it doesn't. It just means that BOTH of those references must be nil'd out before it is released.

Comment: Oh.. So how come delegate definitions are typically weak? What's the point of even having a weak reference then? Couldn't you just make all references strong?

Comment: @Savagewood Delegate references are `weak` to avoid retain cycles.

Comment: What is a retain cycle? Sorry for the constant questions

Comment: @Savagewood A retain cycle is where two objects have strong references to each other. The end result is that neither of them are ever deallocated.

Comment: Oh from what @CrimsonChris said I think I get the idea. The delegate would never be released if the definition was strong